# replacing figures in a column to others if condition is not met in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with this column "Party". There are about 50 different names for "Party". I only want to retain 2 values 'democrat' and 'republican' and the rest all change to "Others". How do I go about doing it using isin function?

```
partytokeep = df.party_detailed.isin(['democrat', 'republican'])
partytokeep


df['party_detailed'].where(df.party_detailed == 'partytokeep'), other='others', inplace=True)
df

my syntax error is as such:
  File "<ipython-input-29-c7c062b05249>", line 1
    df['party_detailed'].where(df.party_detailed == 'partytokeep'), other='others', inplace=True)
                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `(` in  line `df['party_detailed'].where(df.party_detailed == 'partytokeep'), other='others', inplace=True)`

The error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` tells the same, that it has to do somthing with syntax.
The correct syntax would be:

```
df['party_detailed'].where((df.party_detailed == 'partytokeep'), other='others', inplace=True)
```

Also once you have calculated boolian `partytokeep`
you can directy set values

```
df.loc[~partytokeep, 'party_detailed'] = 'others'
```

Comment: 0


i did the above and all my values all changed to 'Others' instead of keeping 'democrat' and 'republican'and replacing all others to 'Others'

Comment: Try `df['party_detailed'].where(~df.party_detailed .isin(['democrat', 'republican']), other='others', inplace=True)`

Comment: got syntax error:File "<ipython-input-79-ce47dd7f93e3>", line 1
    df['party_detailed'].where((~df.party_detailed.isin[(['democrat', 'republican']), other='others', inplace=True)
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

i did the above and all my values all changed to 'Others' instead of keeping 'democrat' and 'republican'and replacing all others to 'Others'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).